# CloudWatch Alert for a group of EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

Right now I manually creating the same set of alerts for a bunch of EC2 that I have. Is it possible to make a default set of alerts, and set those to a selected EC2 instances.

So I have a consistent group of alerts and I'm sure I didn't miss anything?

Comment: Only if your instances are in an auto-scaling group.

Comment: Nooo, you serious? What about adding alerts to any new EC2 instance that I create? Isn't there a way to automate this stuff?

Comment: If you create them via cloudformation or terraform, you can include the alerts in your template.